# How can I store my google sheet cred file inside my python code, I dont want to store file in my PC, i want to write cred inside my code?

Tags: python, gspread

import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

```
import requests
import datetime
import pandas as pd

def writedata():
    # Connect to Google Sheet
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds.json',scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
    sheet = client.open("Min15Scan").sheet1
    symlist = sheet.col_values(1)
    print(symlist)
```

#creds file is store in my PC but I want to store cred data inside my code

```
#Sample cred json data
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "crafty-haiku-272664766",
  "private_key_id": "f1466f265175a46ee86da0badsasd2badsa33ba4sa51937b65d79c8a4606",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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\nHEzasacgV5kfunTa12IVCu6pg==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "googledrive@crafty-haiku-276606.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "108588760741771314111",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/googledrive%40craddffty-haiku-276667676.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generally bad practice to store credentials directly in the code. There are a lot of security reasons behind this, which I recommend you research. Practically, do you really want to update your code if the credentials change?

Anyway, if you decide that you truly want to do this, you can store the credential data as a string or dictionary and then use the appropriate method:

- [`from_json()`](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.service_account.html#oauth2client.service_account.ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json)
- [`from_json_keyfile_dict()`](http://from_json_keyfile_dict)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using environment variables to use credentials safely inside of your code.
Try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IolxqkL7cD8).